# Change the color of the selected row in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to XAML therefore please pardon me for this basic question.
Basically i am trying to change the color of the selected row in DataGrid. Currently when the row is selected the color is by default light blue but i dont understand where the color is set from.
I want to change the selected color and also the text color of the selected row.
Below is my code.

```
        <DataGrid Name="TransferCallDataGrid"
              Margin="0 10 0 0"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Agents}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAgent}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              HeadersVisibility="Column" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" 
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              BorderBrush="Transparent" 
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" 

              RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width=".7*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="{Binding Path=AgentState, Converter={StaticResource AgentStateConverterResource}}" Width="3" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Id}" Style="{DynamicResource GridTextColumnStyle}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First Name" Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Style="{DynamicResource GridTextColumnStyle}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Last Name" Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LastName}" Style="{DynamicResource GridTextColumnStyle}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State" Width="1.1*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=AgentState, Converter={StaticResource AgentStateTextConverterResource}}" Style="{DynamicResource GridTextColumnStyle}" Foreground="{Binding Path=AgentState, Converter={StaticResource AgentStateConverterResource}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

And following is the styling of the row i believe

```
  <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding NewItemMargin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA.

**-------------------------EDIT---------------------------------------------------**

This is the edited code block. 
I am able to change the background color now but unable to change the foreground color. My code is below.

```
<USD:DynamicsBaseHostedControl.Resources>
    <demo:AgentStateConverter x:Key="AgentStateConverterResource"/>
    <demo:AgentStateTextConverter x:Key="AgentStateTextConverterResource"/>

    <Style x:Key="GridTextColumnStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF686767"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="NoWrap"/>
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>

        <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">

            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding NewItemMargin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
            </Trigger>

            <!--<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
            </Trigger>-->
        </Style.Triggers>
        <!--<Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue" />
        </Style.Resources>-->
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">


            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#022648" />
                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post all my code here which works for the foreground color.
Maybe you have some other style interfering with the cell foreground...
(It's very quick and dirty example, but the text color is yellow if selected)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        </Border>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsNewItem" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding NewItemMargin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                            Value="2" />
                </Trigger>

            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Employees" XPath="/Employees/*">
            <x:XData>
                <Employees xmlns="">
                    <Employee Name="Terry Adams" Type="FTE" EmployeeNumber="1" />
                    <Employee Name="Claire O&apos;Donnell" Type="FTE" EmployeeNumber="12345" />
                    <Employee Name="Palle Peterson" Type="FTE" EmployeeNumber="5678" />
                    <Employee Name="Amy E. Alberts" Type="CSG" EmployeeNumber="99222" />
                    <Employee Name="Stefan Hesse" Type="Vendor" EmployeeNumber="-" />
                </Employees>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid Name="TransferCallDataGrid"
          Margin="0 10 0 0"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employees}}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAgent}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          HeadersVisibility="Column" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" 
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" 
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          BorderBrush="Transparent" 
          SelectionUnit="FullRow" 

          RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID" Width=".7*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"  Width="3" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First Name" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Last Name" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State" Width="1.1*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please check my edited question i have pasted the code i am using.

Comment: Still unable to change foreground /font color

Comment: Is there any other way to change the font color as you have shown previously
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
               Color="#FF00aa"/>

Comment: x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"

Comment: I have figured out it.. The GridTextColumnStyle is overriding it but if i bypass it, it works fine. However, i want to apply the styling of GridTextColumnStyle when the row is not selected and when it is selected i just want to change the color to white. How can i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the DataGridCell Style:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

To answer your question where the default color is comming from:
it comes from the System.Colors.HighlightBrushKey.

You can override it, and this would be another solution. Add this to your resources:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
               Color="#FF00aa"/>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. I have 2 questions.

1. Why did you select the TargetType="DataGridCell" why not TargetType="DataGridRow" as in this case i am trying to change the color of the row.

2. I want to change the text color of the font when the row is selected but i want to do it with only three columns i.e. ID, FirstName and LastName, I want the 4th column font color to remain as is. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Answer to Q1:
It seems the DataGridCell Style is overriding the DataGridRow Style

Comment: Answer to Q2: in the DataGridCell Style, set the Foreground property:
 <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                    </Trigger>

Comment: How did you figure out that DataGridCell is overriding DataGridRow?

Comment: And as i told i want to change foreground property of 3 columns but the fourth one will remain as it is

Comment: I am setting the foreground color but it is not working. It only works for background color.

Comment: I think that's a seperate topic for another question

Comment: Can you please tell me about setting up foreground color?

Comment: This workes in my example:
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

Comment: I dont understand why but in my case the foreground property is not working.